# How do I back up my Linux system

Tags: linux, backup

I am using Yocto distribution of Linux. And currently, I am looking to back-up my system following the guide:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

The part I am having trouble with is that

> and go to the root of your filesystem (we use this in our example, but
>   you can go anywhere you want your backup to end up, including remote
>   or removable drives.) Code: `cd /`

How do I double-gaurantee that by typing `cd`, it will go to the very very top folder of ENTIRE linux system, and how do I double ensure that the back-up will back up ENTIRE THINGS of the linux system?

Comment: `cd` and `cd  /` is not the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to backup to your own harddrive, then it needs at least 50% free space.

Typically people do not backup all their binaries, but rather their data (the data that is in the /home directories)

sudo mkdir /homeBackups

sudo cp -a /home /homeBackups/.

sudo tar -cvf homeBackups.tar .

sudo gzip homeBackups.tar

Then store the final homeBackups.tar.gz somewhere safe. (done!)